# save UUID returned by AttributeConverter as pg-uuid

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, uuid

I have some class **CustomUuid**, that stores **java.util.UUID** in a custom format. But I need to save that as pg-uuid and have that custom format everywhere outside DAO layer. I tried to use javax.persistence.AttributeConverter but I'm getting

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "custom_uuid" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 223
```

As I understand, UUID isn't automatically converts to pg-uuid (or other embedded type), and to do it, I need to add annotation @Type, but this annotation doesn't work with @Converter. Attaching some pieces of code.

I will be very grateful for any help!

```
@Convert(converter = CustomUuidConverter.class)
@Column(nullable = false)
private CustomUuid customUuid;
```

and **CustomUuidConverter.java**

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class CustomUuidConverter implements AttributeConverter<CustomUuid, UUID> {

    @Override
    public UUID convertToDatabaseColumn(CustomUuid uuid) {
        return uuid == null ? null : uuid.toJavaUuid();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomUuid convertToEntityAttribute(UUID uuid) {
        return uuid == null ? null : new CustomUuid(uuid);
    }
}
```

As DB I use postgresql (and liquibase for creating tables)

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution ?

Comment: Same problem, found any solution?